# Calculating heights of columns of 0 and 1's and Bool values for full heights

Tags: python-3.x

Desperately need help! I have tried transversing the 2d arrays and using row.count() but nothing has worked so far.

Python unsure how to start this I want to find the heights of the 1 columns.
Input [[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1]]

Output [2,3,3,1]

making a function which takes a 2d array like the example below and gives a true or false value. True only there are 2's going the full length of a column.
[[2,1,1,0],[2,1,1,0],[2,1,1,0]

[ True, False, False, False ]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the heights of the 1 columns"? Also, what have you tried so far that doesn't work?

Comment: I mean counting how many 1's from the bottom of the 2d array to the top.                                               eg.                    [1,0,1]                                                                                                                                        .                         [1,1,1]  so for the first column the height would be 2, second would be 1 and third 2

Comment: If you use `numpy` it's trivial. `list((np.array(lst) == 2).all(axis=0))` should work where `lst` is your `list` of `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is an example:**

```
def fun(arr):
    # assuming given array's elements are contain row values, this is the array that its elements are contain column values
    cols = [[arr[i][j] for i in range(len(arr))] for j in range(len(arr[0]))]
    # iterate the above array, if the iterating element is consists just 2's, return true, else return false
    return [all(i == 2 for i in n) for n in cols]
    
print(fun([[2,1,1,0],[2,1,1,0],[2,1,1,0]]))
```

this gives you the output `[True, False, False, False]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy`: [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_intro.asp)

```
import numpy as np
M=[[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1]]
a=np.sum(M,axis=0)
print(a)----> output = [2 3 3 1]

a_list = a.tolist()
a_max = max(a_list)
print((a > a_max-1).tolist()) ---> [False,True,True,False]
```